# d3.js - prevent "clustering" with parent / other groups in force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm facing an issue right now where I'm trying to make a force-directed graph that's smart about how it clusters. Currently I'm getting the following, which as you can see, has a very broken layout in regards to readability. I would much prefer to have each child group cluster with itself, and repel sibling groups, so it's a bit easier to follow. Preferably, I'd also like these clusters to be equally distributed in a circle around the parent node so when there are a lot of nodes, they're at least more readable than they would otherwise be if they all clustered on one side of the parent.

I did a bit of research, and I would like something similar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mccannf/5548435), but I'm not sure how I can apply that to my site. For reference, my site layout is based off of [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) force layout.

[image]

Comment: Your graph and the one you would like it to look like are both examples of force layout, the latter being a clustered force layout (google for examples). So, basically it is a matter of fitting your data to the clustered layout. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501072/problems-with-latest-cluster-force-layout-example) of data format and processing that can be used in a clustered force layout...this should help.

Comment: From what you're describing, it sounds like a [radial tree layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) may be more suitable. You're also saying that you've found something that you like, but are not sure how to use it. Without any more detail, we can't help you with that.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Thanks! That looks helpful, and I'll see if I can work something out based on that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I was actually hoping to keep them clustered in a circle around their parent element. Also, I should have been more clear - In that example I found, what I wanted was the element of clustering in groups, and not intermingling with other groups. I wasn't sure how to apply the `padding` idea in the given example to my example.

Comment: @Seiyria What do you mean by `padding` here? In the example it's just a sort of offset applied during the collision detection.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Right, and that's what I was thinking would help, is if I did something like that. I just used `padding` as a point of reference to help explain exactly what part of the example I thought would be beneficial.

Comment: @Seiyria Have you tried taking that example and plugging your data into it?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No, I haven't. I didn't think that using that example _verbatim_ was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Seiyria I'm suggesting that it might be easier to start from that example and adapt it rather than starting with what you have and trying to adapt the example to that.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the link distance and increasing the (negative) charge on the force layout?  That should encourage a tighter relationship between parents and children while encouraging greater spread overall.  Just watch out -- if charge is to big, nodes will bounce around erratically and get tangled up instead of spread out.  Try `force.charge(-100).linkDistance(10)` for starters.  Another option if the data is a tree structure, as @LarsKotthoff said, is to use [a tree layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) to guarantee neat clustering.  Force layout it somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: To clarify: in the cluster example, a special cluster function is used to move each node closer to the center of their cluster.  However, that's exactly the same thing that the links do in a regular force layout -- move the linked nodes closer to each other.  A shorter link distance means that linked nodes will be pulled closer together.  The charge value is more complicated, but if a node has a "negative charge" it will push other nodes away -- regardless of whether they are linked or not.  The two values have to balance out to get a nice layout.

Comment: @AmeliaBR It's going to take a bit more playing with, but I think increasing the negative charge actually does this really well! I hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately I have to keep my link distance a bit higher due to the number of children in some trees, and if it's too small they'll hide underneath one another. Either way, I think I have a passable implementation now.

Comment: You could always make the link distance a function of the same factors that you are using to decide the size of the node, e.g. `.linkDistance(function(d){return nodeSize(d.target) + nodeSize(d.source) + 5;})`, where `nodeSize(nodeData)` is a convenience function that you also use for setting the node's radius based on the number of children.  If you get it working, add & accept an answer with your code snippet.

Comment: @AmeliaBR That's what I ended up doing; in the event where a node had a lot of children, it had to increase its own node distance accordingly. This also made the graph look a bit more "random" because some nodes had a few children, some had more, and overall I think it looks really nice. I'll post my code now. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up playing with the d3 force options a bit, and I came across this as a viable solution:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(function(d) { 
        return d.target._children ? d.target._children.length * 30 : 
            d.target.children ? d.target.children.length * 30 :
            60;
    })
    .charge(-400)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .friction(0.45)
    .linkStrength(0.6)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);
```

`gravity` / `friction` / `linkStrength` are not necessary but make transitions overall smoother; having a very negative `charge` was the key component to solving my original problem.

Much thanks to @AmeliaBR for pointing me in the right direction!